# Debugger for RascalMPL

Tags: rascal

I want to know if there are work being to include a debugger in RascalMPL, if so when should I expect it. It would greatly improve the efficiency of the development of languages with rascal, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- There is a full-blown interactive debugger in the Rascal Eclipse plugin
- We are currently porting that feature to VScode (specifically the debugger protocol.)

That should take a couple of weeks at least, so in the meantime you have Eclipse or "println debugging"

Comment: an experimental debugger has been released how exactly does it work? @jurgen

Comment: It's a public secret @PiusArhanbhunde; since we believe the debugger needs more alpha & beta testing before we claim it as a supported feature. It is enabled by using `:set debugging true` in the terminal. You can put breakpoints in the editor by clicking in the left margin.